# Sniffing my networks traffic illegal?

Tags: wifi, sniffer

So this is a pretty straight forward question.

If I setup a free and open wifi access point called "Free&Tots-Secure" then sniff all the traffic of people that connect to it, does that violate the computer fraud and abuse act?

Expanding on the above question, what if I use a tool like ssl stripper to force http traffic only. Does this constitute a breach of the CFAA?

We are assuming the following.

1. This is an open access point that is setup by me and is tunneling traffic through my actual home internet network.
2. Does NOT notify users when they connect their data is being captured and inspected.
3. Is not being used maliciously but only for my own education and advancement of capabilities with real world scenarios.

Comment: If you're looking for legal advice, ask a lawyer, not a bunch of random people on the Internet.

Comment: Not being a lawyer, I'm gonna go with `not legal`. The first rule of educational hacking/security/pentesting/wtv is "only do it on your on machines, on your own closed network".

Comment: While they don't usually worry too much about it, setting up an open wifi hub is probably in violation of your internet provider's TOS if you're doing this on a residential connection.

Comment: For the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act, it will depend more on what you do with the data you collect.

Comment: It probably violates some wiretapping-esque law, depending on your state. Just as an example, in California, it is illegal to record phone conversations without the consent of *all* parties involved. Your system is similar is spirit and probably violates some law... Maybe if you put up a warning banner, warning people that their traffic would be intercepted it would be legal... maybe not... I'm just guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of question has depends answers. The answer varies depending on the policies of owner of open WiFi and plans among other factors.
but This question specially has 2 aspects: (second aspect may be your answer)

**First one:** connecting people to an open WiFi network, without having the owner's permission and following his/her terms of service is illegal.

**Using a neighbor's wireless access point without the neighbour's permission is illegal.**

the examples are:

Many U.S. states prohibit unauthorized access to computer networks including open Wi-Fi networks. While interpretations of these laws may vary, some precedents have been set:

- 2007 - a man in Michigan was fined for using the Wi-Fi hotspot of a local cafe, from his car.
- 2006 - Illinois man David Kauchak was fined for unauthorized use of a local agency's Wi-Fi access point.
- 2005 - a Florida man faced felony charges for piggybacking onto a neighbor's Internet connection without their permission.
- **Similar restrictions on using open Wi-Fi networks exist outside the U.S. as well:**
- 2006 - In Singapore, a teenager received a probationary sentence for wirelessly. accessing a neighbor's Internet connection without their permission.
- 2005 - In the U.K., Gregory Straszkiewicz was fined and his computer confiscated for using a local resident's Internet service illicitly.

Therefore, as yours rights:Just as entering a home or business without the owner's permission is considered trespassing (even if the doors are unlocked), likewise accessing wireless Internet connections (even open access ones) can be considered an illegal activity. At a minimum, obtain consent from the operator of any Wi-Fi access point before using their service. Read any online Terms of Service documentation carefully when signing on, and contact the owner offline if necessary to ensure compliance.

**So if people connect to your open WiFi whiteout your permission they accept the risks and your terms of services by default.**

**Second one:**  if someone provides an open WiFi, specially for malicious proposes in some cases it can considered as crime. since your proposes are not malicious it is better that you consider a terms of service, in order to probable future states.

and also read this news:

[Sniffing open WiFi networks is not wiretapping, judge says](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/09/07/sniffing-open-wifi-networks-is-not-wiretapping-judge-says/)

P[acket-Sniffing Laws Murky as Open Wi-Fi Proliferates](http://www.wired.com/2010/06/packet-sniffing-laws-murky/)

[Public Wifi Data = Radio Waves Legally Accessible by Anyone](http://www.privatewifi.com/federal-judge-rules-that-wifi-sniffing-is-perfectly-legal/)

Comment: You are wrong about the permission thing. If you have the owners permission, then its Always ok to use the network (else the owner would not be allowed to use the network either). The permission can in many times be given by the WiFi name. (eg "Free Public Wifi Hotspot"). In some cases, its ok to use the network given certain terms, for example buying a cup of coffee at the local café gives you wifi during the visit. However, you CANNOT ask a existing user, because that user may have get a permission by the network owner, that he cannot lend out or share with someone else.

Comment: You wrote that you need the "service provider's permission". Thats incorrect, the contract is between the neighbour and service provider. If the neighbour gives you permission to access the network, you can assume the neighbour has permission to share his Connection with his ISP. The ISP can sue or terminate the neightbor for sharing access. Some ISPs prohibit sharing, but its only cheap ISPs that do it. ("only the person who is stated on the contract may use the Connection"). In those cases, its a contract violation to even let family members to use the Connection. But still, its not ILLEGAL.

Comment: I told that may not be legal not absolutely

Comment: Its Always legal to do it with permission from the owner. Its the same: Visiting a private webpage (that is clearly intended for a closed group) without the owners permission is illegal (computer intrusion), regardless of if its password protected or not. But its NOT illegal to visit a webpage that you have the owners permission to visit, even if his ISP contract prohibit servers and you know the contract prohibit servers.

Comment: I wrote: " may not be legal even with their permission" because sometimes it is related to type of permission,because the meaning of "Using" can be changed. by the way. you can edit my answer, whole of the answer is not incorrect, why do we discuss?